# Installing manually PHPDocumentor on Mac

Tags: documentation, documentation-generation, phpdoc, code-documentation

After trying to install PHPDocumentor with PEAR install with no success, i tried it manually as is detailed on the official website: http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/installation.html

I downloaded the files and i make an alias on /usr/bin/ but when i try to execute phpdoc.php via terminal y it shows an error.

This is what i try:

```
> cd /usr/bin/
> ./phpdoc.php
```

And this is the error:

```
PHP Warning:  include_once(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpdocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/../../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpdocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Bootstrap.php on line 72
PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpdocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/../../vendor/autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/bin/') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpdocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Bootstrap.php on line 72
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'phpDocumentor_Task_Runner' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpdocumentor/bin/phpdoc.php on line 37
```

I am using Mac Os X and as you can see, i use MAMP to run Apache.
What's going on here? Why it tries to open a file which doesn't exist? (because it really doesn't exist inside PHPDocumentor folder)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try :

```
curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php

php composer install
```

on phpdocumentor2 directory (you should find composer.json)

[Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) is a dependency manager for php. So it will populate phpdocumentor projet with external/vendor dependencies

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more? What does exactly Composer does? What should i do then?

Comment: composer is just a dependency manager. And as you can see on your error some dependencies are missing.

Comment: Ok, i have download it and i have created the composer.phar file. Then i placed it on the PHPDocumentor folder where the composer.json is.
Now i run "php composer.phar install" and it throws me this error: http://s2.subirimagenes.com/privadas/1827614captura-de-pantalla.png

Comment: i can't open your image. Else why you don't use pear to install phpdoc ?

Comment: Well, i am having many troubles with PEAR. It seems i have more than one PEAR destiny and i don't get anything works with it. (and i have already waste so many time with it).
The image again: http://postimage.org/image/5niqca363/

Comment: Yeah you need git. It's a source code management, one of the most famous with SVN. Why ? Because the other dependencies are saved on git repository (certainly https://github.com/). Im on linux/windows env so I can't help you with git installation but it's really easy for unix like system. So you may not have any probs

Comment: Ok, i have installed git. So then i run "php composer.phar install" and i have it installed. Then i created a symlink from <PHPDOC_PATH>/bin/phpdoc.php to my bin folder /usr/bin and i renamed it to phpdoc. (as its said on the phpdocumentor manual installation) http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/installation.html
Now, i tried to run "phpdoc" and it says: "-bash: /usr/bin/phpdoc: Permission denied" then i tried it with sudo and it says "sudo: phpdoc: command not found".
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I have noticed composer uses PEAR. So... as i am having problems with PEAR... can it be that one the cause?
I have finally executed phpdoc with phpdoc.php command as its said here http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/basic-usage.html and i still having the same problem as the one i posted on my question. I guess composer is not doing it well...

Comment: This is what i get with "php composer.phar install": 
    `Initializing PEAR repository http://packages.zendframework.com
    Packages names will be prefixed with: pear-zf2/
Initializing PEAR repository http://pear.symfony-project.com
Packages names will be prefixed with: pear-symfony/`

Comment: The last message that you posted is perfectly normal; please note that you are trying to install the development version which is not fully production-ready yet. The message about permission being denied is probably because you do not have the execution flag set; try `chmod +x /usr/bin/phpdoc.php` (without or with sudo)

Answer (score 3):

Try this to install Composer into your MAMP php bin:

```
cd yourapp/ && curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php
```